# Tree Fold operation?

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

I am taking a class in Haskell, and we need to define the fold operation for a tree defined by:

```
data Tree a = Lf a | Br (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

I can not seem to find any information on the "tfold" operation or really what it supposed to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I always think of folds as a way of systematically replacing constructors by other functions. So, for instance, if you have a do-it-yourself `List` type (defined as `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`), the corresponding fold can be written as:

```
listfold nil cons Nil = nil
listfold nil cons (Cons a b) = cons a (listfold nil cons b)
```

or, maybe more concisely, as:

```
listfold nil cons = go where
    go Nil = nil
    go (Cons a b) = cons a (go b)
```

The type of `listfold` is `b -> (a -> b -> b) -> List a -> b`. That is to say, it takes two 'replacement constructors'; one telling how a `Nil` value should be transformed into a `b`, another replacement constructor for the `Cons` constructor, telling how the first value of the `Cons` constructor (of type `a`) should be combined with a value of type `b` (why `b`? because the fold has already been applied recursively!) to yield a new `b`, and finally a `List a` to apply the whole she-bang to - with a result of `b`.

In your case, the type of `tfold` should be `(a -> b) -> (b -> b -> b) -> Tree a -> b` by analogous reasoning; hopefully you'll be able to take it from there!

Comment: This is exactly right.  However, I think it's useful to add this point to your answer: if `tfold` is defined correctly, then `tfold Lf Br` should be the identity function on `Tree a`—a function that takes a tree and returns an identical one.  (Likewise for your example, `listfold Nil Cons` is the identity over `List`.)

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you define that a tree should be shown in the following manner,

```
<1 # <<2#3> # <4#5>>>
```

Folding such a tree means replacing each branch node with an actual supplied operation to be performed *on the results of fold recursively performed* on the data type's constituents (here, the node's two child nodes, which are themselves, each, a tree), for example with `+`, producing

```
(1 + ((2+3) + (4+5)))
```

So, for leaves you should just take the values inside them, and for branches, recursively apply the fold for each of the two child nodes, and *combine* the two results with the supplied function, the one with which the tree is folded. (**edit:**) When "taking" values from leaves, you could additionally transform them, applying a unary function. So in general, your folding will need *two* user-provided functions, one for *leaves*, `Lf`, and another one for combining the *r*esults of *r*ecursively folding the tree-like constituents (i.e. branches) of the *branching nodes*, `Br`.

Your tree data type could have been defined differently, e.g. with possibly empty leaves, and with internal nodes also carrying the values. Then you'd have to provide a default value to be used instead of the empty leaf nodes, and a three-way combination operation. Still you'd have the fold defined by *two* functions corresponding to the *two cases* of the data type definition.

Another distinction to realize here is, *what* you fold, and *how* you fold it. I.e. you could fold your tree in a *linear* fashion, `(1+(2+(3+(4+5)))) == ((1+) . (2+) . (3+) . (4+) . (5+)) 0`, or you could fold a linear list in a *tree-like* fashion, `((1+2)+((3+4)+5)) == (((1+2)+(3+4))+5)`. It is all about how you parenthesize the resulting "expression". Of course in the classic take on *folding* the expression's structure follows that of the data structure being folded; but [variations do exist](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold#Tree-like_folds). Note also, that the combining operation might not be strict, and the "*r*esult" type it consumes/produces might express *compound* (lists and such), as well as atomic (numbers and such), values.

*(update 2019-01-26)* This re-parenthesization is possible if the combining operation is associative, like `+`:  `(a1+a2)+a3 == a1+(a2+a3)`. A data type together with such associative operation and a "zero" element (`a+0 == 0+a == a`) is known as "Monoid", and the notion of folding "into" a Monoid is captured by the `Foldable` type class.

Comment: This response is making the same error as most of the responses: writing a "fold" function that substitutes the `Br` constructor but fails to do the same for the `Lf` constructor.

Comment: @sacundim Ah, I see your point with the identity transformation. You're right, the application of a separate unary function on leaves' values should be explicated here. It was left ambiguous in my response.

Comment: (just so it is clear, that oversight in this answer has long been fixed.)

Answer (score 1):

A fold on a list is a reduction from a list into a single element. It takes a function and then applies that function to elements, two at a time, until it has only one element.  For example:

```
Prelude> foldl1 (+) [3,5,6,7]
21
```

...is found by doing operations one-by-one:

```
3 + 5 == 8
8 + 6 == 14
14 + 7 == 21
```

A fold can be written

```
ourFold :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
ourFold _         [a]        = a -- pattern-match for a single-element list. Our work is done.
ourFold aFunction (x0:x1:xs) = ourFold aFunction ((aFunction x0 x1):xs)
```

A tree fold would do this, but move up or down the branches of the tree. To do this, it first need  to pattern-match to see whether you're operating on a Leaf or a Branch.

```
treeFold _ (Lf a)   = Lf a -- You can't do much to a one-leaf tree
treeFold f (Br a b) = -- ...
```

The rest is left up to you, since it's homework. If you're stuck, try first thinking of what the type should be.

Comment: Now that the question is old enough, would be nice to see the full answer, for those who want to learn, and don't have homework.

Answer (score 1):

A fold is an operation which "compacts" a data structure into a single value using an operation. There are variations depending if you have a start value and execution order (e.g. for lists you have `foldl`, `foldr`, `foldl1` and `foldr1`), so the correct implementation depends on your assignment.

I guess your `tfold` should simply replace all leafs with its values, and all branches with applications of the given operation. Draw an example tree with some numbers, an "collapse" him given an operation like `(+)`. After this, it should be easy to write a function doing the same.

Comment: I downvoted you for the same reason as I explain in my comment to Will Ness' answer.  For the `Tree` datatype the poster shows, `tfold` shouldn't "replace all leafs with its values" as you say.

Comment: That depends on how you define "fold", as the TO gave not enough information about the expected function. What I describe is just the behavior e.g. of a `foldr1` or `foldl1` for a commutative operation, because this is conceptually the simplest version. If you're so damn sure that you're "correct", I would suggest to actually *answer* the question instead of downvoting everybody you slightly disagree with.